# Dynamically get the newly added textbox value

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically adding a new textbox on a click event.

I am not able to get the value of each textbox, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**In my html page:**

```
   <div id="job-container">
    <p>
        <label>Job Property</label><br>
        <input name="JobProperty[1][job_property]" />
    </p>
  </div>

    <a href="javascript:" id="add-new-jobproperty"  
    onclick="createJobProperty()">Add new job</a>
```

**In my Javascript code**

```
let i = 2;

function createJobProperty() {
    let template = `

    <p>
        <label>Job Property</label><br>
        <input name="JobProperty[${i}][job_property]">
    </p>`;

let container = document.getElementById('job-container');
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = template;
container.appendChild(div);
definedLength=i;
i++;
```

}

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't clear. What value are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a class to inputs and then get them by className (since by tag name, you may have other inputs), and iterate through each of them to get values.

`<input class='my-input' name="JobProperty[${i}][job_property]">` use this code to add a new input

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('my-input');

Array.from(inputs).forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.value);
});

//or

Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(element) {
    console.log(element.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
let i = 2;

function createJobProperty() {
    let template = `
    <p>
        <label>Job Property</label><br>
        <input name="JobProperty[` + i + `][job_property]">
    </p>`;

    let container = document.getElementById('job-container');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = template;
    container.appendChild(div);

    let input = container.querySelector("input[name='JobProperty["+i+"][job_property]']");
    // do what ever you want with the input

    definedLength=i;
    i++;
}
```